# Prove the given surface has Gaussian curvature zero

Tags: differential-geometry

> If a regular surface is covered by a surface patch all of whose $u$- and $v$-coordinate curves are geodesics, then it has Gaussian curvature zero.

How can I show the above statement? Could you give any hint?

Edit: Using the following formula: Let $S$ be an oriented regular surface and $\sigma:U\subset\Bbb R^2\to V\subset S$ be a surface patch. Let $\gamma:I\to V$ be a regular curve which can be expressed as $\gamma(t) = \sigma(u(t),v(t))$ for some smooth functions $u,v:I\to\Bbb R$. Then $\gamma$ is geodesic if and only if $u''+(u')^2\Gamma_{11}^1+2(u'v')\Gamma_{12}^1+(v')^2\Gamma_{22}^1 = 0$ and $v''+(u')^2\Gamma_{11}^2+2(u'v')\Gamma_{12}^2+(v')^2\Gamma_{22}^2 = 0$.

From this, if we consider $\gamma$ as a coordinate curve (letting $u(t)=t$ and $v(t)=t$ resp.) then I get $\Gamma_{11}^1 =\Gamma_{11}^2 = \Gamma_{22}^1=\Gamma_{22}^2 = 0$. I don't know how to get further. I'm in introductory course in differential geometry by the way. So I want some explanation in elementary way.

The formula I wrote is in p.290 of [this textbook](https://www.pdfdrive.com/differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-e183809914.html).

Comment: What formula are you using for Guassian curvature? Where in the calculation have you got stuck or confused?

Comment: @Nick In fact, this exercise comes from the section that introduces Christoffel symbols. I think any formula would be allowed.
Using the fact that the coordinate curves are geodesics, I found that $\Gamma_{11}^1 = \Gamma_{11}^2 = \Gamma_{22}^1 = \Gamma_{22}^2 =0$. And I don't know how to go further

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry ? If you have verified that the Christoffel symbols are zero, then the curvature tensor itself is identically zero.

Comment: @Nick But not all of the symbols are zero. Only four of them I think.

Comment: How about this formula, then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_definitions ? Since the coordinate lines are geodesics, $\nabla_1 e_1 = 0$, etc... Maybe you can fill in the rest of the details.

Comment: @Nick Well, I've never heard about 'tensor' thing. It's an introductory course in differential geometry. Could you lower the level?

Comment: That is why I asked you at the beginning what formulas you're using. Without more context, and an explanation of what you've tried, and what you've learned in class, it's hard to give an explanation. People giving answers won't know if they are being too advanced, and using things you have not learned. I would suggest editing your question, and show how much of the calculation you can do on your own, and where you get stuck. This way we know what methods/formulas you are supposed to be using.

Comment: @Nick I edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you do the case when the $u$- and $v$-curves are orthogonal? At the moment, I don't see how you got four Christoffel symbols to vanish.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that is the case when $F=0$. Then I know the guassian curvature is $K = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}})+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}))$

Comment: Yes, and you can easily deduce that $E_v=G_u=0$ in this situation. I'm not yet 100% convinced that the result is correct in general. I know how to prove it several ways when the parameter curves make a constant angle (not necessarily a right angle).

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. But how could I in general? Actually, this exercise is in the section introducing Christoffel symbols. Any approach using that?

Comment: Other than the right-angle case, I would wait until differential forms *or* until local Gauss-Bonnet (which is the nicest argument). But see my answer. Without a constraint on the angles, it's just false. (I'm beginning to think that the author of your book should have written a solutions manual — for himself — to check a lot of his exercises!)

Comment: @TedShifrin I read your answer, and what does the 'finding local coordinates whose coordinate curves are tangent to two given linearly independent vector fields' show?

Comment: That means that the $u$-curves will be everywhere tangent to the vector field $X$ and the $v$-curves will be everywhere tangent to the vector field $Y$. (I am *not* saying that $X = \partial\mathbf x/\partial u$, however.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Does that mean that Guassian curvature is nonzero?

Comment: I said you could do this on *any* surface (locally, of course)! Let me make that explicit.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, now I can see what it is. So, making surface patch small enough, we can always get geodesic $u$- and $v$- curve.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm claiming. But the constant angle situation is *far* more restrictive, and that forces $K=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then could you answer the case when the angles are constant? (Can't believe that book is my textbook...)

Comment: You can see moving frames proof as Exercise 11 on p. 106 of my text. The local Gauss-Bonnet proof is suggested in Exercise 12 on p. 90 (for right angles only, but it immediately generalizes) by considering holonomy around small "parallelograms." If you work on either of these and get stuck, you can ask another question or ask me in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is false. Locally, *on any surface whatsoever* you can always find coordinates so that the $u$-curves and $v$-curves are geodesics. It is a standard result from differential equations that *on a surface* I can find local coordinates whose coordinate curves are tangent to two given linearly independent vector fields.

Choose a frame $X_0,Y_0$ (unit vectors) at $p_0$. Take the geodesics in those tangent directions. Call them $C$ and $\Gamma$. Take the tangent vectors to be $X$ and $Y$ respectively along those curves. Now choose $Y$ smoothly along $C$ and $X$ smoothly along $\Gamma$ extending these, maintaining linear independence. Now follow geodesics  from points of $C$ in the direction of $Y$ and follow geodesics from points of $\Gamma$ in the direction of $X$. Define the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ in the obvious way in a small neighborhood of $p_0$. We have constructed these so that they are tangent to geodesics at each point.